# How do I deal with boss favoring a coworker with a higher title who uses my work as their own?

Tags: work-environment

How do I handle trouble with boss and coworker? I always receive praise but now am having trouble and it seems because my boss is favoring a project manager. I am a sr analyst and there is a project manager however they are not my manager. I’ve had issues with the project manager not giving me information, not returning calls or messages, not looking over things for days which delayed me sending things out, saying they will inform me but they do not, speaking to me rudely, taking my work word for word and the saving it so their name would appear and speaking over me as though they did the work, and giving me the incorrect information only to then be told by our boss taht is not what he wants and this is wrong. I have told our manager multiple times and that only made things worse. The boss now also ignores emails and messages and calls and only speaks to me when no one else is around for him to ask them ask me a question. And when I am working on things he requires that everyone in the group is present however with each of them he speaks to them one on one to provide information. Recently there was a project that we were all waiting to receive a file to do and the both of them were not communicating. I reached out to both and the project manager said to not ask boss anything and to hold and they will get back to me once they are done. At 4 still not hearing I contacted the director who my boss reports to only because the director is the contact who was receiving the file. I only asked if he did to which he said he sent to the boss and I said oh okay. He asked if he sent to me since I’m the only who was doing this project and it was due the following day and I only responded saying not yet but I’m sure he will. After that about 15 minutes later only did the project manager call me and say what was needed to do. She proceeded to say she was speaking with boss so she could wrap her head around the file and now at the end of the day I am left to do work due in a short time. After that she then proceeded to say I was wrong to ask the boss anything as she gets in trouble because it makes it look like she is not doing her job and never would she have ever called the director of the boss was ignoring her. I said I only called the director as I would anyone to ask if they received anything that we as a team were waiting for as no one informed me about anything and I was only trying to help us collectively and anyone else would have done the same. She said absolutely not would anyone have ever done the same and I am not a project manager and I need to listen.

Was I wrong to have called the director? I did not inform him of the behaviors going on. I only called him as he was the contact to gather the information we were waiting on. Am I going to get in trouble?

Comment: Please can you use some paragraphs. It is very hard to read at the moment. Also it feels like you could remove a lot of detail so we can just see the important bits.

Comment: As a senior analyst, are all your emails and voicemails this long? If they are, I completely understand that they're "not returning calls or messages". I wouldn't either.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like there is some confusion all around here.

A project manager is usually responsible for delivering projects, not managing people. So, it's normal for a project manager to be the "face" of a project and to present the work done on the project to the project's stakeholders.

However, a project manager is usually NOT the person deciding the what should be done (project scope) or how it should be done (project plan). They tend to focus more on budget, timelines and progress towards the goals. The project scope usually comes from the project's stakeholders (sounds like this is the director in your case). And the details of the project plan usually come from the team members doing the work (you in your case).

In your situation, it sounds like you are misunderstanding the role of the project manager. While they are not your manager, they are probably accountable for delivering the projects you are working on together. This includes responsibility for reporting out on project progress, which may be what you are interpreting as the project manager presenting your work as her own. I would be surprised if anyone thought that the project manager was the one actually doing the work.

That said, it sounds like your project manager is not doing a great job of project managing. Specifically, she is:

1. **NOT properly interpreting the project requirements.** If she does not have the expertise to do this herself, she should rely on those in the team that do. Potential reasons for this behavior could be: trying to prove herself to her boss, trying to shield you from what she thinks is not important for you to be doing (or was told not to bother you with), or simply not realizing she should be relying more on your input. You might approach this with a conversation with her saying that getting the wrong requirements is leading to delays and some frustration and see if there are ways you can be more involved in the process to get to a successul conclusion faster.
2. **NOT facilitating communication.** A project manager is supposed to be a facilitator. That is, the project manager should be actively working to make sure no one on the team is blocked, and that everyone who needs to be talking to each other is talking to each other. If she's not doing this well, it could be that she is overloaded or that she thinks she needs to do more of the work herself rather than just connecting the right people and the right information. For the former, you might speak with her to see if there are lighter weight ways you can get the information from her (e.g., ask to be CC'd on relevant communication so you get it right away). For the latter, you might need to have a chat with her about communication styles. For example, if you are quite pedantic about how you receive information, you might need to take a step back and see if you can be more flexible in how you get what you need (e.g., don't demand 100% clear and committed requirements but instead accept the general idea and then seek out those who can fill in the details). In either case, you probably need a conversation specifically on how the lack of information is slowing you down. For example, with a deadline the next day, you might suggest it would be faster all around for you to be in the room going through the information with them.

Lastly, it was a mistake to go to the director. This is a CYA move of last resort as it WILL cause both your project manager and your boss to dislike working with you. It would have been better to be more direct with the project manager and your boss. If they're not responding to calls or e-mails, try walking over to talk to them directly (assuming this is possible in a COVID world). If not possible, follow up by phone. Remind them that the day is slipping away and much work is left to be done so it would be good to get a head start on the information that's available even if they don't yet know 100% what to do with it.

Comment: This helps me in discussing. It has been going on awhile. With the director I only asked if the information was received and didn’t speak Poorly of anyone. something similar happened and I did not press for details and was given the project she was supposed to do but was told by our boss to take it over the day before and she would do the response file. Her other portion again was not done and I was tasked with it. This is why I was trying to be proactive to help us all as I was not sure if we even received the information. I will not ever do that again though. Thank you for your feedback.